# Filter on results in RadGrid Column

Tags: javascript, c#, html, telerik

I have a radgrid that returns the results of the text from one of two search boxes on the website. We want to be able to filter on the results of the search in the grid by column. I have added AllowFilteringByColumn = 'true' in the radgrid parameters, but when you enter text into the radgrid filter textboxes nothing refreshes.

I have looked into the difference between server side and client side filtering, but I really don't want to make another call to the database if I don't have to. Creating a asp sqldatasource took too long because of the amouont of data returned. Is there not a simple way to filter on the result set without making another call? NeedDataSource calls getDataGrid which pulls the text from the search, queries the database and returns. Our grid columns are created in the prerender.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="grid">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" EnableLinqExpressions="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Skin="WebBlue" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="Both" OnNeedDataSource="NeedDataSource" PageSize="50" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender"  AllowMultiRowSelection="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="true">
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="UsePointer" />
                    <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" CommandItemDisplay="bottom">
                        <SortExpressions><telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="field1" SortOrder="Ascending" /></SortExpressions>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="commandHeader" HeaderStyle-Width="30px" Exportable="false" UniqueName="checkCol">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckAll(this)" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cboxSelect" runat="server" onclick="unCheckHeader(this); enableMassUpdate()" OnCheckedChanged="GridCheckBoxChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToExcelButton="false" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowRefreshButton="false"/>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true"  EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" >
                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                        <ClientEvents  OnRowSelecting="RowSelecting" OnRowSelected="RowSelected" OnCommand="ClearForm"  />
                        <KeyboardNavigationSettings EnableKeyboardShortcuts="false" AllowSubmitOnEnter="false" AllowActiveRowCycle="false" ></KeyboardNavigationSettings>
                    </ClientSettings>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>

    protected void NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
            {

                (source as RadGrid).DataSource = getDataGrid("RadGrid1");
            }

    protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    GridColumn checkCol = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("field1");
                    checkCol.OrderIndex = 1;
                    GridColumn assetDeptCol = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("field2");
                    assetDeptCol.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(115);
                    assetDeptCol.HeaderText = "Field2";
                    assetDeptCol.OrderIndex = 2;
                    GridColumn assetIDCol = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("field3");
                    assetIDCol.Display = false;

etc....
RadGrid1.Rebind();
;
```

Comment: So in NeedDataSource, you are filtering your results, but the page is not posting back in order to reach this code?

Comment: The results are filtered in getDataGrid where we build are sqlBuilder query and add the filters based off of the text input. Then NeedDataSource pulls the source data from the getDataGrid by passing through RadGrid1. But if the user filters on their managed assets, but then wants to filter on a particular assets in a building, how can I instruct the radgrid to filter on the original NeedDataSource data pull without posting back, or is that not possible?

Comment: Where I work, we use a separate RadSearchBox control which is tied in to the rad grid via Ajax, so although it does a post-back and rebinds the grid with filter, it is not a full post back of the page and still looks/works good.  The user can also search on different fields using the context menu of the RadSearchBox.  I don't think you can filter on the client when your RadGrid is bound in code-behind like you suggest.

Comment: Haha i was afraid someone would say that. I wasn't the person who originally designed it this way so that's why I have been having such troubles trying to do something that seems really easy from multiple sites/posts I have read. But yeah since our Grid columns are created on the backend, it complicates things. Appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: I think if you use a SqlDataSource it's all pretty automatic.  They make it look so easy in the demos, and I think that's part of it.  Good luck man!